# Determining if the Excel file is still open with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

Is there a way to determine if an excel file is open in vb.net? When I open a certain file with my program and close the excel file before i close my form then my form won't close at all. Any kind of insight would help, thanks.

This controls the close button on the form

```
Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
            ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If (fileOpen = False) Then
        e.Cancel = False
    Else
        xlWorkbook.Save()
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If

End Sub
```

So I changed it to this and it works for some reason

```
 Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
         ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If (fileOpen = False Or fileOpen = True) Then
        e.Cancel = False
    Else
        xlWorkbook.Save()
        xlApp.Quit()
    End If

End Sub
```

"fileOpen" gets set to True when a file is selected and opened in excel. I don't think it ever gets put back to False unless it automatically does it when Excel closes?

Comment: Um that is strange. That shouldn't be happening. Can you share the code that you are using to interact with Excel.

Comment: Do you want your form not to close when excel file is open? or it is the error you are getting? (Got confused with the code provided)

Comment: I kind of figured it out. If I change it to 

Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

        If (fileOpen = False Or fileOpen = True) Then
            e.Cancel = False
        Else
            xlWorkbook.Save()
            xlApp.Quit()
        End If

    End Sub

Then it works for some reason, I guess because it tests if the file is open or closed and before it was only testing if the file didn't exist? I'm still confused with this though. Doesn't seem correct.

Comment: This statement `If (fileOpen = False Or fileOpen = True) Then ` is meaningless. It is always true and your code never reach the part where you close the excel file. You say that your form never close, do you have an error message when you call xlWorkbook.Save()?

Comment: Even when I just put it as If (fileOpen = True) Then...If excel is closed before my form is closed then my form won't close. I'm not getting any error when I call xlWorkbook.Save()